# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'WindowsApplication1.Helpers+SalePayment[]'

Tags: json, vb.net

Please HELP!!!!
I am trying to deserialize a Json. The problem I have is when I have just 1 "SalePayment"(Since this is not coming as array). If I have several "SalePayment" like in the example json then my code works fine.

This is the json

```
{
    "@attributes": {
        "count": "1",
        "offset": "0",
        "limit": "100"
    },
    "Sale": {
        "saleID": "55",
        "timeStamp": "2016-06-11T13:08:16+00:00",
        "discountPercent": "0",
        "completed": "true",
        "archived": "false",
        "voided": "false",
        "enablePromotions": "true",
        "isTaxInclusive": "false",
        "referenceNumber": "",
        "referenceNumberSource": "",
        "tax1Rate": "0",
        "tax2Rate": "0",
        "change": "0",
        "receiptPreference": "printed",
        "displayableSubtotal": "2700",
        "ticketNumber": "220000000055",
        "calcDiscount": "0",
        "calcTotal": "2700",
        "calcSubtotal": "2700",
        "calcTaxable": "0",
        "calcNonTaxable": "2700",
        "calcAvgCost": "0",
        "calcFIFOCost": "0",
        "calcTax1": "0",
        "calcTax2": "0",
        "calcPayments": "2700",
        "total": "2700",
        "totalDue": "2700",
        "displayableTotal": "2700",
        "balance": "0",
        "customerID": "0",
        "discountID": "0",
        "employeeID": "1",
        "quoteID": "0",
        "registerID": "1",
        "shipToID": "0",
        "shopID": "1",
        "taxCategoryID": "0",
        "SalePayments": {
            "SalePayment": [
                {
                    "salePaymentID": "40",
                    "amount": "500",
                    "createTime": "2016-06-11T13:08:16+00:00",
                    "archived": "false",
                    "remoteReference": "",
                    "paymentID": "",
                    "saleID": "55",
                    "paymentTypeID": "2",
                    "ccChargeID": "0",
                    "refPaymentID": "0",
                    "registerID": "1",
                    "employeeID": "1",
                    "creditAccountID": "0",
                    "PaymentType": {
                        "paymentTypeID": "2",
                        "name": "Check",
                        "requireCustomer": "false",
                        "archived": "false",
                        "internalReserved": "false",
                        "type": "user defined",
                        "refundAsPaymentTypeID": "0"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "salePaymentID": "41",
                    "amount": "500",
                    "createTime": "2016-06-11T13:08:16+00:00",
                    "archived": "false",
                    "remoteReference": "",
                    "paymentID": "",
                    "saleID": "55",
                    "paymentTypeID": "3",
                    "ccChargeID": "0",
                    "refPaymentID": "0",
                    "registerID": "1",
                    "employeeID": "1",
                    "creditAccountID": "0",
                    "PaymentType": {
                        "paymentTypeID": "3",
                        "name": "Credit Card",
                        "requireCustomer": "false",
                        "archived": "false",
                        "internalReserved": "false",
                        "type": "user defined",
                        "refundAsPaymentTypeID": "0"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "salePaymentID": "42",
                    "amount": "1300",
                    "createTime": "2016-06-11T13:08:16+00:00",
                    "archived": "false",
                    "remoteReference": "",
                    "paymentID": "",
                    "saleID": "55",
                    "paymentTypeID": "6",
                    "ccChargeID": "0",
                    "refPaymentID": "0",
                    "registerID": "1",
                    "employeeID": "1",
                    "creditAccountID": "0",
                    "PaymentType": {
                        "paymentTypeID": "6",
                        "name": "Debit Card",
                        "requireCustomer": "false",
                        "archived": "false",
                        "internalReserved": "false",
                        "type": "user defined",
                        "refundAsPaymentTypeID": "0"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "salePaymentID": "43",
                    "amount": "400",
                    "createTime": "2016-06-11T13:08:16+00:00",
                    "archived": "false",
                    "remoteReference": "",
                    "paymentID": "",
                    "saleID": "55",
                    "paymentTypeID": "1",
                    "ccChargeID": "0",
                    "refPaymentID": "0",
                    "registerID": "1",
                    "employeeID": "1",
                    "creditAccountID": "0",
                    "PaymentType": {
                        "paymentTypeID": "1",
                        "name": "Cash",
                        "requireCustomer": "false",
                        "archived": "false",
                        "internalReserved": "true",
                        "type": "cash",
                        "refundAsPaymentTypeID": "0"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "taxTotal": "0"
    }
}
```

This is the CLASS
    Public Class Helpers

```
Public Property attribute As Attributes
Public Property Sale As Sales

Public Class Attributes
    Public Property count As String
    Public Property offset As String
    Public Property limit As String
End Class

Public Class PaymentType
    Public Property paymentTypeID As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property requireCustomer As String
    Public Property archived As String
    Public Property internalReserved As String
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property refundAsPaymentTypeID As String
End Class

Public Class SalePayment
    Public Property salePaymentID As String
    Public Property amount As String
    Public Property createTime As DateTime
    Public Property archived As String
    Public Property remoteReference As String
    Public Property paymentID As String
    Public Property saleID As String
    Public Property paymentTypeID As String
    Public Property ccChargeID As String
    Public Property refPaymentID As String
    Public Property registerID As String
    Public Property employeeID As String
    Public Property creditAccountID As String
    Public Property PaymentType As PaymentType
End Class

Public Class SalePayments
    Public Property SalePayment As SalePayment()
End Class

Public Class Sales
    Public Property saleID As String
    Public Property timeStamp As DateTime
    Public Property discountPercent As String
    Public Property completed As String
    Public Property archived As String
    Public Property voided As String
    Public Property enablePromotions As String
    Public Property isTaxInclusive As String
    Public Property referenceNumber As String
    Public Property referenceNumberSource As String
    Public Property tax1Rate As String
    Public Property tax2Rate As String
    Public Property change As String
    Public Property receiptPreference As String
    Public Property displayableSubtotal As String
    Public Property ticketNumber As String
    Public Property calcDiscount As String
    Public Property calcTotal As String
    Public Property calcSubtotal As String
    Public Property calcTaxable As String
    Public Property calcNonTaxable As String
    Public Property calcAvgCost As String
    Public Property calcFIFOCost As String
    Public Property calcTax1 As String
    Public Property calcTax2 As String
    Public Property calcPayments As String
    Public Property total As String
    Public Property totalDue As String
    Public Property displayableTotal As String
    Public Property balance As String
    Public Property customerID As String
    Public Property discountID As String
    Public Property employeeID As String
    Public Property quoteID As String
    Public Property registerID As String
    Public Property shipToID As String
    Public Property shopID As String
    Public Property taxCategoryID As String
    Public Property SalePayments As SalePayments
    Public Property taxTotal As String
End Class



End Class
```

And this is the code

```
        Dim OrdersSaleList As Helpers
        OrdersSaleList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Helpers)(json)
```

I am getting this error

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'WindowsApplication1.Helpers+SalePayment[]' because the type
>   requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix
>   this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or
>   change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g.
>   not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array
>   or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object. Path
>   'Sale.SalePayments.SalePayment.salePaymentID', line 1, position 3821.

Comment: parse the json from `json2csharp.com` to generate the strongly typed object.

Comment: Did it already on http://jsonutils.com/

Comment: No , because this is working when I only have several "SalePayments " because it is declared as an array on the class, but if I only have 1 "SalePayments "  the it doesn't work.

Comment: Try changing `Public Property SalePayment As SalePayment()` to `Public Property SalePayment As List(Of SalePayment)`

Comment: You left out the "Helpers" class unless all that is inside Helpers like the post  sort of indicates

Comment: Same thing , it works when I have several "Payments" but for one I am getting the same error. The only difference is the error message is showing System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WindowsApplication1.Helpers+SalePayment]' instead of into type 'WindowsApplication1.Helpers+SalePayment[]'

Comment: Plutonix 22 , correct all that is inside Helpers Class

Comment: Well, thats whats wrong.  Helpers should be {Sale, Attributes} although you will need to alias `Attributes` probably

Comment: I modify the post and added . I forgot to type those on the post.
    Public Property attribute As Attributes
    Public Property Sale As Sales